# Qt windowflags in Linux

Tags: c++, qt

Image of the main application and child application

[image]

Im using Linux Ubuntu 16.04 and Qt Application 
I have a problem about a windowflags in qt, that when I enter in full screen mode, my application model bar and menu bar hides since my application opens 2 application.

So I decided to make another application to Qt::FramelessWindowhint in order the other application cannot be open and only the main application will be shown.
My problem is when I dragged the application to another monitor, the 2nd application will hide. 
Can anyone help me about this problem?

Comment: Can you add some more information like what you expect and what you experience? The snapshots would be good as it's a visual thing. The other thing you could do is check the DPI settings of your applications. Maybe, due to the difference in DPI settings of different monitors the applications are not able to scale well. Another thing you could look at is the layouts of the applications.

Comment: @Azeem thanks for your suggestions. But the main problem is that the child application hides or maybe move somewhere on the 2nd monitor(I use laptop and normal monitor) when I use a FramelessWindowHint to make the child application to not inherit the main application when I use the full screen mode. I tried different WindowFlags but when I dont use Framelesswindowhint, e.g Qt::Window, it will make 2 applications appear and the full screen mode affects the title bar of my application and it becomes hide.

Comment: That sounds like a modality issue i.e. `childWin->setWindowModality(Qt::WindowModal);`. You can look at that. From debugging standpoint, you could make the child window print its coordinates on screen to be sure that it is there.

Comment: I tried also the modality. But I need the child should be included in the main application as it moved to another monitor. But it should be Framelesswindowhint used so that the main application can be on full screen mode and the menu bar and the title bar should not be hide. Let me know if something you can't understand. Thank you so much. Very appreciated for your knowledge and help.

Comment: Right. Some snapshots would be great if could manage that to understand the problem. I'm not sure if it would be reproducible if you'd share the code.

Comment: I dont know how to send a snapshots here. Im newbie here in stackoverflow. I have a snapshots in mine.

Comment: Already post a snapshots of my problem in my primary post up. I return temporarily to Window and not in framelesswindow to show you the problem. And then I make the child application frameless so that the main application (in left picture) can use full screen mode without hiding the menu bar and the widget bar. Thanks

Comment: Already fixed the problem. I just only fixed the position of the child application. Thank you.